# weird error -- link error ? with gcc

Tags: gcc, g++

I can't compile anymore with gcc .

Using `gcc -o run mytest.cpp` ,gives:

```
mytest.cpp:12:9: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
mytest.cpp:12:14: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
mytest.cpp: In constructor ‘matrix::matrix()’:
mytest.cpp:23:26: error: invalid conversion from ‘int**’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
mytest.cpp:24:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
mytest.cpp:25:22: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
mytest.cpp:28:13: error: no match for ‘operator~’ in ‘~matrix()’
mytest.cpp:28:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/ios:43:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/iostream:40,
                 from mytest.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/bits/ios_base.h:89:3: note: std::_Ios_Fmtflags std::operator~(std::_Ios_Fmtflags)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/bits/ios_base.h:89:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘matrix’ to ‘std::_Ios_Fmtflags’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/bits/ios_base.h:129:3: note: std::_Ios_Openmode std::operator~(std::_Ios_Openmode)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/bits/ios_base.h:129:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘matrix’ to ‘std::_Ios_Openmode’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/bits/ios_base.h:167:3: note: std::_Ios_Iostate std::operator~(std::_Ios_Iostate)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/bits/ios_base.h:167:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘matrix’ to ‘std::_Ios_Iostate’
mytest.cpp:28:14: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
mytest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mytest.cpp:45:3: error: ‘class matrix’ has no member named ‘add’
mytest.cpp: At global scope:
mytest.cpp:52:28: error: no ‘matrix matrix::add(matrix)’ member function declared in class ‘matrix’
```

The code uses:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
```

If I compile a simple hello world code using only iostream ,it gives me:

```
/tmp/ccGrqvwo.o: In function `main':
simple.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `std::cout'
simple.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/tmp/ccGrqvwo.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
simple.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
simple.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
...
```

but if I compile it with  `g++ -o run simple.cpp` ,instead of `gcc` ,it works!

Doing the same to the first code ,doesn't work! (I mean using g++)

Comment: In case of gcc, the error messages are telling you that you have forgotten to link with `libstdc++`. g++ automatically links with `libstdc++`.

Comment: As for the first half, it is unclear and without the code, it is hard to tell.

Comment: `gcc` is for compiling C code. `g++` is for compiling C++ code. Repeat as necessary until the difference becomes obvious...

Comment: @Ali:The code runs fine(tested) .I don't know what I did with gcc and now it doesn't work.

Comment: @twalberg:The code is c++ (I used to compile c++ with gcc with no problem ) The thing is that I did sth with gcc and now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally...

I removed again completely gcc ,g++ .
I reinstalled ,I symlink gcc and g++ and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

The first error looks as innocuous as a missing semicolon on line 11 of `MyTest.cpp`. Until you've fixed that, you can probably ignore the subsequent errors as a syntax error can cause the compiler's parser to find all kinds of spurious other errors.

As for the link issue, as others have pointed out, `g++` will automatically link with `libstdc++`, whereas you must instruct `gcc` to do so via `-lstdc++`.

Comment: :Hello,unfortunately it is not the semicolon.The code works fine.It just uses 'cmath,cstdlib,cstdio'.Something broke with these.